# PHP If Else with Navigation Menu

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create an if else statement where if the "if" part is true, a menu icon is displayed that says "Registration" and takes the user to a registration page. If the "else" part is true, the menu will display the user's name that is registered. I have attached basically how I would like it to look, I just do not know how to incorporate my div into a PHP if else statement.

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['email'] == '')
{
    "<div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="registration.php"> Registration</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
    </div>"
}

else 
{
    "<div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a> "Greetings " . $_SESSION['fname'] </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
    </div>"
}

?>
```

Comment: you forgot the `echo` and concatenate strings properly

Comment: ...not to mention no closing statements - *parse error*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick. As mentioned by @Ghost, you need echo and you needed to change a few quotes to single quotes.

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['email'] == '')
{
    echo "<div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a href='registration.php'> Registration</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
    </div>";
}

else 
{
    echo "<div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                <li>
                Greetings " . $_SESSION['fname'] . " </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
    </div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use php whitin html

the php code is only considered between php tags so anything else is put directly to browser

as i can see only one part of your html changes so a better design would be

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>

   <div id="cssmenu">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                    <?php if ($_Session['email']=='') {                       
                    ?>
                    <a href="registration.php">Registration</a>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <a href="#">Greetings -> <?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?></a>


                    <?php }?>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
```